# "a moment next of such confusion" and one other question related to a sample from an old story

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, literature

I would like to ask two questions regarding the following sentence:

> There was a **moment next of such confusion** that I did not see what
> happened to Riquette, **for** the sight of my companion kneeling on the
> dusty boards and praying with a curious sort of passionate happiness,
> while tears pressed between her covering fingers—the strange wonder of
> this made me utterly oblivious to minor details.

1. Is "next" adverb here? I am unsure of the meaning when placed like that.
2. Is "for" here the conjuction, meaning "because/since"? I thought so, but then I realized the sentence sounds somehow incomplete.

Comment: Yes, there is a 'disconnect' in the sentence, as though the writer were speaking and had slightly lost their thread. However, expressing it logically would have made the sentence even more difficult to understand. _For the strange wonder of the sight of my companion kneeling (...) made me utterly oblivious to minor details._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There was a moment **next** of such confusion that I did not see what happened to Riquette, [...]

I believe **next** is a pronoun here. The author is referring to the exact next moment after his/her narration when the incident(confusion) took place. [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/next)

> [...] what happened to Riquette, **for** the sight of my companion kneeling on the dusty boards [...]

**for** is acting, as you presumed, like a conjunction here. Its meaning are, *because; as*. [Source](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/for)